# SharePoint 2013 - eDiscovery and deduplication

Tags: records-management, records-center, ediscovery, deduplication

Does anybody here have experience with using deduplication features for eDiscovery in SharePoint 2013?  From what I can see there are some deduplication options when you run the Export process.

How effective are those out of the box features versus any third party solutions that might exist?

Did you implement hashing algorithms into your solution?  If so, can you expand on what are the best options / methods? (MD5 Hash / SHA-1)

What are some good use cases for deduplication in eDiscovery?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/18cfac66-1ed8-4a96-814b-25319b0f1686/deduplication-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral